# Microsoft Azure - Limit resource group elements - custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

my goal is to limit the creation of resource type per owner/collaborator of a specific Resource Group.
Example: 
User_Group_XXX accessed by account YYY:

- MAX 2 VM - Standard D2s v3
- MAX 1 Kubernetes Cluster with 2 node - Standard DS2 v2

**NO more than that and NO other type of resources.**

How can I include those limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible by definition. Azure Policy looks at individual resource properties, so there is no way to have it do something like that (so check other resources and apply policy based on those resource to a the resource in question).

although, you could easily create a policy to only allow virtual machines\aks clusters.

again, policies cannot be scoped to users

Comment: Thx, so if I understand correcly, I need to setup policy at Subscription level? this will have impact on all resource group?

Comment: right, but you wouldn't be able to control who can\cannot create those resources (RBAC is used for that) or the amount of resources created

Comment: So I can limit on all accounts (owner/collaborator) accessing to specific SubScription->ResGroup via dedicated policies. I cannot govern at User level. Not completely clear what I can or cannot do with RBAC.

Comment: No, you can grant specific users\groups specific roles at specific scopes. policies can be used to alter what or how resources are deployed (block specific settings, or location, or resource types). policies != rbac

Comment: Is it any practical example on how to create a policy to only allow virtual machines\aks clusters?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allowed-resource-types